# jquery plugin datatables: How can I remove rows which the second cell has value "animal" and third cell has value "tiger" in one table?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm new for this jquery plugin "Datatables".

My Question:

I have builed a table with this plugin.

Now I want to remove rows which the second cell has value "animal" and third cell has value "tiger" in one table.

My code likes:

```
var table = $('#tableID').DataTable();
table.rows().each(function() {
    var rowData = this.data();
    var cell2 = rowData[1];
    var cell3 = rowData[2];
    if(cell2 == "animal" && cell3 == "tiger") this.remove().draw();
});
```

Problem 1: rows() doesn't return all rows, just return only the first row.

Problem 2: is "this.data()" valid?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can we have some more info on your structure?

Comment: I would like to retrive all rows in the table and remove the spec rows